# Error present in Tensorboard: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to use TensorBoard for creating insights during model training.With it, I want to check how my  model is training, which epoch delivers the best result, and more. However I come across the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-e7c9b8bd2922> in <module>
     18 model.fit([x_train['input1'], x_train['input2']], y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = 10, verbose = 0, 
---> 19           callbacks = [tf_board])
     20 
     21
```

### My Code

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import datetime # optional

# Important!
%load_ext tensorboard
%reload_ext tensorboard

# Pass a directory to save logs
log_dir = '/home/pedro/MyDrive/Transfer_Learning/Models/logs'

# Let's create our callback
# TensorBoard(directory, histogram_freq, update_freq, 5) 
# -> str(range(profile_batch)) or str(profile_batch)
tf_board = TensorBoard(log_dir, histogram_freq=8, update_freq='batch', profile_batch='5, 10')

# And fit our callback inside our training data
model.fit([x_train['input1'], x_train['input2']], y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = 10, verbose = 0, 
          callbacks = [tf_board])
                    
# Use this magic function to visualize
%tensorboard --logdir '/home/pedro/MyDrive/Transfer_Learning/Models/logs'
```

Comment: Try this `(5, 10)`, instead of this `'5, 10'`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, you have probably already solved your problem but I am posting here for future guys with the same problem as me.

You just have to update your Tensorflow, TensorBoard (and tensorboard-plugin-profile) to be version `>=2.2.0`, as mentioned in the [official Profiler documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/profiler#prerequisites). The Tensorboard callback probably expected a different parameter in the previous versions.